# Improving Box Factory solution

Tags: algorithm

[Box Factory](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/1781488/dashboard#s=p2) is a problem in Google Code Jam 2012 Round 1C. It is similar to the Longest Common Subsequence problem, and they have given an [O(n^4) solution](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/1781488/dashboard#s=a&a=2) for it. However, at the end of the analysis it says that *another improvement can reduce this again to O(n^3)*. I am wondering what optimization can be done to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### O(n^4) Algorithm

The dynamic programming approach solves for f[x][y] = the maximum number of toys that could be placed in boxes using the first x runs of boxes and the first y runs of toys.

It solves this by considering the boxes of the last type for runs between a+1 and x, and toys of the last type for runs between b+1 and y.

The O(n^4) algorithm loops over all choices for a and b, but we can simplify by only considering critical values of a and b.

### O(n^3) Algorithm

The key point is that if we have a,b such that we have more boxes than toys, then there is no point changing a to get even more boxes (as this will never help us make any more products).  Similarly, if we have more toys than boxes, then we can skip considering all the cases of b which would gives us even more toys.

This suggests a O(n) algorithm for the inner loop in which we trace out the boundary of a,b between having more toys and having more boxes.  This is quite simple as we can just start with a=x-1, and b=y-1 and then decrease either a or b according to whether we currently have more toys or boxes.  (If equal then you can decrease both.)

Each step of the algorithm decreases either a or b by 1, so this iteration will require x+y steps instead of the x*y steps of the original method.

It needs to be repeated for all values of x,y so overall the complexity is O(n^3).

### Additional Improvements

A further improvement would be to store the index of the previous run of each type as this would allow several steps of the algorithm to be collapsed into a single move (because we know that our score can only improve once we work back to a run of the correct type).  However, this would still be O(n^3) in the worst case (all boxes/toys of the same type).

Another practical improvement is to coalesce any runs in which the type was the same at consecutive positions, as this may significantly simplify test cases designed to expose the worst case behaviour in the previous improvement.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In this O(n^4) or O(n^3) estimation, what is the "n"?  I've read the Google problem description, the Google answer description and your answer (above), but it's still far from obvious what "n" is.

Comment: n is max(N,M) where N is the number of runs of boxes, and M is the number of runs of toys.  A more accurate measure of order is O(NM(N+M))